# OnItemClickListener NullPointerException on some items but not all of them

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I coded an OnItemClickListener as I always used to coded it:

```
@Override
protected AdapterView.OnItemClickListener setDrawerClickListener(){
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener customListener=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent lancia=null;
            HomeActivity.this.closeDrawer();
            try {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        log.d("CLICK","I0: "+i);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        log.d("CLICK","I1: "+i);
                        if (makeLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            hideMakeMenu();
                            showMenu();
                        }
                        HomeActivity.this.changeDrawerSelected(new boolean[]{false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false});
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        log.d("CLICK","I2: "+i);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        log.d("CLICK","I3: "+i);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        log.d("CLICK","I4: "+i);
                        if (makeLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                            hideMenu();
                            showMakeMenu();
                        }
                        HomeActivity.this.changeDrawerSelected(new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false});
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        log.d("CLICK","I5: "+i);
                        //lancia = new Intent("com.recquest.LIST");
                        //lancia.putExtra("WHICH", "AROUND");
                        showMakeMenu();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        log.d("CLICK","I6: "+i);
                        lancia = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                        lancia.putExtra("WHICH", "MINE");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        log.d("CLICK","I7: "+i);
                        break;
                }
                if (lancia != null)
                    startActivity(lancia);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    };
    return customListener;
}
```

It is inside a method as my activity extends another BaseActivity I created myself. When one item is clicked the log correctly shows which one is pressed. The issue is that cases 1 and 4 works perfectly but the other ones throw a NullPointerException in getView method of the custom adapter(the rendering of the listView is perfect).
Here is how i initialize the adapter, as can be seen, all items are initialized the same way and then rendered nicely on the screen:

```
private DrawerItem[] initializeDrawerArray(boolean[] selected){
    DrawerItem[] pz=new DrawerItem[8];
    if(selected[0]){
        pz[0]=new DrawerItem(null,DrawerItemType.PROFILE_ITEM,0,true);
    }else{
        pz[0]=new DrawerItem(null,DrawerItemType.PROFILE_ITEM,0,false);
    }
    if(selected[1]){
        pz[1]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_home),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.home_red,true);
    }else{
        pz[1]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_home),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.home,false);
    }
    pz[2]=new DrawerItem(null,DrawerItemType.DIVIDER,0,false);
    if(selected[3]){
        pz[3]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_most),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.most_red,true);
    }else{
        pz[3]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_most),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.most,false);
    }
    if(selected[4]){
        pz[4]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_new),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.newreq_red,true);
    }else{
        pz[4]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_new),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.newreq,false);
    }
    if(selected[5]){
        pz[5]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_around),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.aroundme_red,true);
    }else{
        pz[5]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_around),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.aroundme,false);
    }
    if(selected[6]){
        pz[6]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_my),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.myreq_red,true);
    }else{
        pz[6]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_my),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.myreq,false);
    }
    if(selected[7]){
        pz[7]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_browse),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.live_red,true);
    }else{
        pz[7]=new DrawerItem(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_browse),DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM,R.drawable.live,false);
    }
    return pz;
}
```

This initializing method is inside the BaseActivity, the one my activity extends.

Anyone got this error before? It is quite strange because I got the error even if nothing is inside the switch case is executed

Edit:
Here is the StackTrace

```
08-11 22:49:15.429  13775-13775/com.recquest.recquestapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.recquest.recquestapp.DrawerAdapter.getView(DrawerAdapter.java:63)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1588)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1315)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1601)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1439)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:931)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1144)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1863)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit2:

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
DrawerItem[] items;
Context mCtx;
int layout;
PicManager mPicManager;
MyLog log=new MyLog();
public DrawerAdapter(Context ctx,int layout,DrawerItem[] items){
    this.items=items;
    this.mCtx=ctx;
    this.layout=layout;
    mPicManager=new PicManager();
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return items.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int i){
    return items[i];
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0){
    return arg0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int arg0,View arg1,ViewGroup arg2){
    View row=arg1;
    DrawerItemHolder holder=null;
    if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)mCtx).getLayoutInflater();
        row=inflater.inflate(layout,arg2,false);
        holder=new DrawerItemHolder();
        holder.back=(RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.background);
        holder.layout=(RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        holder.profilePic=(SvgImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.customShapeImageView);
        holder.divisorio=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        holder.icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.text=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }else{
        holder=(DrawerItemHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    switch(items[arg0].type) {
        case DrawerItemType.PROFILE_ITEM:
            holder.icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.divisorio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (items[arg0].selected) {
                holder.text.setTextColor(this.mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_red));
                holder.back.setBackgroundColor(this.mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_menu_back));
                holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(this.mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_menu_back));
            }
            if (mPicManager.getMyPic() != null) {
                holder.profilePic.setImageBitmap(mPicManager.getMyPic());
            } else {
                mPicManager.downloadMyPic();
            }
            LocalProfile local = LocalProfile.getLocalProfile(mCtx);
            if (local != null)
                holder.text.setText(local.nome.toUpperCase() + " " + local.cognome.toUpperCase());
            break;
        case DrawerItemType.REGULAR_ITEM:
            holder.profilePic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.divisorio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.icon.setImageDrawable(this.mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(items[arg0].resID));
            holder.text.setText(items[arg0].name);
            if (items[arg0].selected) {
                holder.text.setTextColor(this.mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_red));
                holder.back.setBackgroundColor(this.mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_menu_back));
                holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(this.mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_menu_back));
            }
            break;
        case DrawerItemType.DIVIDER:
            holder.profilePic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.divisorio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
    return row;
}

class DrawerItemHolder{
TextView text;
SvgImageView profilePic;
ImageView icon,divisorio;
RelativeLayout back,layout;
```

Comment: added, it does not say much to me

Comment: I can't think it is an adapter related issue as it works fine when rendering and in two items click as well

Comment: As per stack trace crash occured at line 63 ? Can you check that line?

Comment: You can post DrawerAdapter code?

Comment: how can the problem be there if the item #4 works? This two items are the same...anyways in that line i set to gone one item of my layout,I'm editing the question putting the adapter as well

Comment: You can log the row position in getview then you can find easily the crash.

Comment: I managed to solve by issue forcing the adapter to reload the holder and preventing it from using row.getTag()

Comment: Do you know what is the issue with it?

Comment: If you not using the ViewHolder pattern  , You will face performance issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your code on line 63 inside of your DrawerAdapter class, that is where the application is breaking. You are using some object that hasn't been initialized yet and making a call with it.

Put a breakpoint at the conditional where you initialize the object. Step through the code. There is not enough information here to tell why the object is not initialized. It wouldn't hurt to put the line numbers in the draweradapter class either.

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I understood that but why does it work on other items? They are initialized by the same code